Quarkus Mailer dynamic multi-tenant / multiple configurations
It seems that Quarkus Mailer is the modern JavaMail replacement for Quarkus. How do I use it for multi-tenancy?
I understand that it supports "static" wiring such as https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#multiple-mailer-configurations
EDIT: I'm building a SaaS where my customers can send emails using my platform to their customers using their own branding. For example, imagine I'm building a Salesforce clone, where salespeople of Company X can send emails from my app, but the emails are "branded" using their own (Company X) mail settings, e.g. from sales@companyx.com. Obviously I want to store email settings of each customer in a DB, instead of manually editing application.properties every time there's a new customer.

Can you provide a few more details on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

@geoand added more details, I hope the use case is clearer.

This is my first approach, We can create custom config source which uses cache-aside strategy using hashMap as instance cache and database as persistence. Ref: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support, https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-config-extensions

I just went through the documentation
https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference#multiple-mailer-configurations
We need to think around where we can save the various tenants and their domain.
If we save tenants info in mail_settings table, we can refer below skeleton code 
create tenant_mail_settings table
CREATE TABLE tenant_mail_settings (
    tenant_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    mail_host VARCHAR(255),
    mail_port INT,
    mail_username VARCHAR(255),
    mail_password VARCHAR(255)
);

Define its entity and repo
@Entity
public class TenantMailSettings {
    @Id
    private Long tenantId;
    private String mailHost;
    private int mailPort;
    private String mailUsername;
    private String mailPassword;

    // Getters and setters
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class TenantMailSettingsRepository implements PanacheRepository<TenantMailSettings> {
    public Optional<TenantMailSettings> findByTenantId(Long tenantId) {
        return find("tenantId", tenantId).firstResultOptional();
    }
}


Tenant Service
@ApplicationScoped
public class TenantService {
    @Inject
    TenantMailSettingsRepository repository;

    public TenantMailSettings getMailSettings(Long tenantId) {
        return repository.findByTenantId(tenantId)
                         .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No settings found for tenant: " + tenantId));
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class DynamicMailerConfig {
    @Inject
    TenantIdentifier tenantIdentifier;
    @Inject
    TenantService tenantService;
    @Inject
    Mailer mailer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void configureMailer() {
        Long tenantId = tenantIdentifier.getCurrentTenantId();
        TenantMailSettings settings = tenantService.getMailSettings(tenantId);
        mailer = MailerBuilder.withSMTPServer(settings.getMailHost(), settings.getMailPort())
                              .withSMTPUsername(settings.getMailUsername())
                              .withSMTPPassword(settings.getMailPassword())
                              .build();
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class MailSender {
    @Inject
    DynamicMailerConfig dynamicMailerConfig;

    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        Mail mail = Mail.withText(to, subject, body);
        dynamicMailerConfig.mailer.send(mail);
    }
}

Identify Current Tenant: Implement a method to identify the current tenant. This might be based on a request header, a token, or any other context-specific data. Here I am hard coding this to 123L for a simple solution
@ApplicationScoped
public class TenantIdentifier {
    public Long getCurrentTenantId() {
        // Logic to get the current tenant ID, e.g., from a request header
        return 123L;  // example tenant ID
    }
}

Here are few of my thoughts on how we can fetch tenantId

Request header

public Long getCurrentTenantId() {
    String tenantIdStr = request.getHeader("X-Tenant-ID");
    if (tenantIdStr == null || tenantIdStr.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tenant ID header is missing or empty");
    }
    return Long.parseLong(tenantIdStr);
}



From subdomain or path by injecting HttpServletRequest

public Long getCurrentTenantId() {
   String serverName = request.getServerName();
   // Extract tenant ID from subdomain, e.g., tenant1.example.com -> tenant1
   String tenantIdStr = extractTenantIdFromSubdomain(serverName);
   return Long.parseLong(tenantIdStr);
}

private String extractTenantIdFromSubdomain(String serverName) {
   return serverName.split("\\.")[0];
}


JWT Tokens by injecting JsonWebToken

public Long getCurrentTenantId() {
    String tenantIdStr = jwt.getClaim("tenant_id");
    if (tenantIdStr == null || tenantIdStr.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tenant ID claim is missing or empty");
    }
    return Long.parseLong(tenantIdStr);
}

Let me know if I understood your question correctly and the skeleton code fits for your requirement.
